# Fast way of changing QLabel border-color?

Tags: c++, qt

A Qt novice here. I constructed a frameless window and I would like its border to gradually change colours over time. I have a separate 'timer' class that runs as a QThread and sends signals in 20 ms intervals, passing a new int a (5 < a < 250) to a slot in QMainWindow. This int is then used to change the border colour of two background QLabels via setStyleSheet. In principle this works, however, the moment I try to drag the window (mind - it is a borderless window - I handle dragging using mouseEvents) - it gets very laggy. It jitters a lot. I am 100% sure that setStyleSheet is what slows down the app by a considerable factor. The computer has enough resources to easily handle more calculations, but there is something distinct about setStyleSheet that just slows Qt down.

Would anyone more advanced in Qt be able to advise what is wrong with the below code, or whether it is possible to somehow bypass properties set by setStyleSheet altogether to achieve the same result more quickly? I really wouldn't mind learning to write a more complex code if the result was more efficient.

Minimum reproducible code:

**updater.h**

```
#ifndef UPDATER_H
#define UPDATER_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class updater : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    updater();
    ~updater();
    bool isStopped;
    bool isFlagged;
public slots:
    void workNow();
    void onExit();
signals:
    void freshUpdate(int);
};

#endif // UPDATER_H
```

**updater.cpp**

```
#include "updater.h"

updater::updater()
{
    isStopped = false;
    isFlagged = false;
}

updater::~updater() {
}

void updater::workNow() {
    int a = 250;
    while (this->isStopped == false) {
        if (isFlagged == false) {
            a = a - 1;
            emit freshUpdate(a);
        } else {
            a = a + 1;
            emit freshUpdate(a);
        }

        if (a == 5 and isFlagged == false) {
            isFlagged = true;
        }

        if (a == 250 and isFlagged == true) {
            isFlagged = false;
        }
        QThread::msleep(20);
    }
}

void updater::onExit() {
    isStopped = true;
}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QThread * T_Updater = new QThread();
    updater * upt = new updater();
    QPointF oldPos;

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow*ui;
    bool locked;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    int m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate;
    int m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate;

public slots:
    void onGuiUpdate(int value);
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    upt->moveToThread(T_Updater);

    QObject::connect(T_Updater, &QThread::started, upt, &updater::workNow);
    QObject::connect(upt, &updater::freshUpdate, this, &MainWindow::onGuiUpdate);

    T_Updater->start();
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate = event->position().x();
    m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate = event->position().y();
}

void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    move(event->globalPosition().x() - m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate, event->globalPosition().y() - m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate);
}
   
void MainWindow::onGuiUpdate(int value) {

    ui->label_40->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(5, 30, 5); border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(100," + QString::number(value) + ",100); border-width: 2px; border-radius: 20px;");
    ui->label_42->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(5, 30, 5); border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(100," + QString::number(value) + ",100); border-width: 2px; border-radius: 20px;");
}
```

Any help with understanding why the above code results in a window that is really jittery while being moved would be very helpful.

Just in case this is important: I work with Qt Creator - Qt 6.1 - MSVC 2019 (64-bit).

Comment: In your code there is nothing of QML

Comment: Right, edited, thanks for pointing this out - what I meant was "background-color: rgb(5, 30, 5); border-style: solid; border-color: rgb...." the string that follows setStyleSheet.

Comment: That's not qml, that's Qt StyleSheet